# How to use Plugins for PopUp

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I try to search plugin jquery for create PopUp of comment. But i don't know how use it and what is plugin that support for Popup. Any one can help me to show simple code and explain

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2013/01/jquery-popup-window-tutorial-plugins.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

<kbd>[**Working jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/y6uyq/)</kbd>

The important things to know are:

One:  You need the references in the `<head>` to these three: (1) the jQuery library, and (2) the jQueryUI library, and (3) the jQueryUI css

Two:  Any div at all can be made into a dialog. The div can have any HTML formatting and elements, including buttons, images, input boxes, etc. The div, with all its formatted elements, will appear as such in the dialog.

Three: Usual practice is to first *initialize* the dialog, but set `autoOpen: false,`, and then later on you can force it to open with a `('#divID').dialog( 'open' )` command.

Four: The dialog will not auto-close when you click the button. You must close it using the `('#divID').dialog( 'close' )` command

Five: There are many settings you can use when initializing the dialog. Among the most useful or intriguing are:
 * **autoOpen:** true/false,
 * **width:** 500, //Note: no 'px'
 * **position:** 'top',
 * **draggable:** false,
 * **closeOnEscape:** false

Six: To re-use a dialog -- that is, to replace its contents and re-open:

```
$('#dlgDiv').html('<div>New stuff goes here</div>');
$('#dlgDiv').dialog('open');
```

Seven: To outright destroy a dialog (allows you to re-create another dlg using `.dialog()`:

```
$('#dlgDiv').dialog('destroy');
```

---

Fully working, stand-alone, cut/pastable example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#thePopup').dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    modal:true,
                    title: 'You can put any title here:',
                    width: 800, //default width is 300px, default height is auto
                    buttons: {
                        Giraffe: function() {
                            alert('You hit subMIT');
                            $('#thePopup').html(''); //empty dlg - always a good idea
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                }); //END dialog init

                $('#mybutt').click(function() {
                    $('#thePopup').html('<img src="http://placekittens.com/150/150">');
                    $('#thePopup').dialog('open');
                });

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

<div id="thePopup"></div>
<input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Show the Popup" />

</body>
</html>
```

Additional Reading:

http://salman-w.blogspot.ca/2013/05/jquery-ui-dialog-examples.html

[How to customise jquery ui dialog box title color and font size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006941/how-to-customise-jquery-ui-dialog-box-title-color-and-font-size)

https://www.udemy.com/blog/jquery-popup-window/

[How do I pass a an element position to jquery UI dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966646/how-do-i-pass-a-an-element-position-to-jquery-ui-dialog)

http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

[jQuery UI dialog button text as a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464843/jquery-dialog-button-variable)

[extend jquery ui dialog (add more options)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902099/extend-jquery-ui-dialog-add-more-options)