# jssor stutter, blink and display random box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I've built a small interactive piece that uses jssor for the image viewer. It's working perfectly except for one small thing. Every once in awhile while clicking through the images, it will sort of stutter/pause and then a box will appear over the image then disappear. Often the entire interface will flash along with it.

There is no pattern as to how to make it do this other than to click through images and then it happens. It doesn't happen on or around the same images or at a set interval.

As for the technology, I'm not doing anything special with jssor, other than normal styling to get things positioned properly.

Has anyone seen this or have any suggestions as to how I might be able to better debug the issue?

Thanks,

-peel

Comment: If no one responds quickly, you will have to post your code (the question may be downvoted/closed without posted code anyways). Also, try to [create a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) -- it takes time, but dramatically assists those trying to help -- and you may even solve it yourself while creating the fiddle (always the best learning result).

Comment: Yeah I was a little wary of posting without code, but I'd basically have to recreate the whole thing since I can't currently share any of the images. I'm just at my wits end with trying to figure it out and thought it was worth a shot.

Thanks for the reply though. If nobody has come across it and responds I may just remove it myself.

Comment: Can you try using a different image viewer, just to see what happens? The jQueryUI dialog is [dead simple to implement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797855/how-to-use-plugins-for-popup/18797998#18797998)

Comment: Yes my next step is just to create my own. This one was just easy to integrate, especially since this is what the boss saw when I was offering suggestions ("I want it exactly like that one we looked at.")

Comment: So in doing some more testing, what appears to be happening is the flash I'm seeing isn't an element appearing over the image, but basically a hole in the image where it's not loading.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. How can you have a hole in the image? How do you know it's not a z-index problem? Seriously, though, try sticking it in a jQUI dialog and let jQuery handle all the z-index stuff -- just for one test. Use the implementation example I posted above: `$('#div_for_dlg').html('<img src="DSC001.jpg" />').dialog('open');`

Comment: Since I'm not able to move this to chat, I'll continue here. I apologize I didn't do a good job of explaining but I am 100% positive it's not z-index. To better explain, when this glitch happens (and it's not consistent) I can see the edges of the image, but whatever is behind it shows through. It appears to be a rendering or memory issue and is probably not the code itself. I will look into testing with jQUI as you noted. I've pretty much always just written my own JS and even when I've used jQuery I tend to stay away from extensions so there's room to learn.

Comment: Rolling your own is usually best -- certainly best way to advance own knowledge. The jQUI dialog suggestion was just for a quick & dirty test. Best wishes.