# Please recommend a media library jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, hyperlink, media

I'm looking for a jquery plugin that will

1. popup a gallery of previously uploaded images
2. upon clicking one of the images, close the poup and insert the image's link into a textarea

I've looked around and can't find any. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is not a jQuery plugin but I believe it may be what you are looking for.http://cksource.com/ckfinder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not likely you will find a jQuery plugin that will do all that...

First, you will need some way of identifying what images have been uploaded. You can use a server-side language (PHP, ASP) to list the files and send the list to the page (perhaps storing the list in an `<input type="hidden"` field), or you can store the file names in a database such as MySQL, and then use a server-side language to send the list to the DOM. Note that you can use AJAX (jQuery is easiest) to request such a list interactively.

Here is a simple post about AJAX: [AJAX request callback using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973386/ajax-request-callback-using-jquery/17974843#17974843)

Next, the pop-up is a separate issue. Once you have the file list, you can use jQuery (again, significantly less verbose than javascript and, IMHO, easier) pop-up a dialog containing the desired image.

For a simple pop-up, I recommend the jQueryUI library's `.dialog()` statement.

Here is an example of jQUI dialog:

[How to use Plugins for PopUp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797855/how-to-use-plugins-for-popup/18797998#18797998)